# Animation, adding geom

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create some kind of animation with ggplot2 but it doesn't work as I want to. Here is a minimal example.

```
print(p <- qplot(c(1, 2),c(1, 1))+geom_point())
print(p <- p + geom_point(aes(c(1, 2),c(2, 2)))
print(p <- p + geom_point(aes(c(1, 2),c(3, 3)))
```

Adding extra points by hand is no problem. But now I want to do it in some loop to get an animation.

```
for(i in 4:10){
    Sys.sleep(.3)
    print(p <- p + geom_point(aes(c(1, ),c(i, i))))
}
```

But now only the new points added are shown, and points of the previous iterations are deleted. I  want the old ones still to be visible. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Either of these will do what you want, I think.

```
# create df dynamically
for (i in 1:10) {
  df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:2,i),y=rep(1:i,each=2))
  Sys.sleep(0.3)
  print(ggplot(df, aes(x,y))+geom_point() + ylim(0,10))
}

# create df at the beginning, then subset in the loop
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:2,10), y=rep(1:10,each=2))
for (i in 1:10) {
  Sys.sleep(0.3)
  print(ggplot(df[1:(2*i),], aes(x,y))+geom_point() +ylim(0,10))
}
```

Also, your code will cause the y-axis limits to change for each plot. Using `ylim(...)` keeps all the plots on the same scale.

**EDIT** Response to OP's comment.

One way to create animations is using the `animations` package. Here's an example.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(animation)
ani.record(reset = TRUE) # clear history before recording
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:2,10), y=rep(1:10,each=2))
for (i in 1:10) {
  plot(ggplot(df[1:(2*i),], aes(x,y))+geom_point() +ylim(0,10))
  ani.record() # record the current frame
}
## now we can replay it, with an appropriate pause between frames
oopts = ani.options(interval = 0.5)
ani.replay()
```

This will "record" each frame (using `ani.record(...)`) and then play it back at the end using `ani.replay(...)`. Read the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/animation/animation.pdf) for more details.

Regarding the question about why your code fails, the simple answer is: "this is not the way ggplot is designed to be used." The more complicated answer is this: `ggplot` is based on a framework which expects you to identify a default dataset as a data frame, and then associate (map) various aspects of the graph (aesthetics) with *columns in the data frame*. So if you have a data frame `df` with columns `A` and `B`, and you want to plot `B` vs. `A`, you would write:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point()
```

This code identifies `df` as the dataset, and maps the aesthetic x (the horizontal axis) with column `A` and y with column `B`. Taking advantage of the default order of the arguments, you could also write:

```
ggplot(df, aes(A,B)) + geom_point()
```

It is possible to specify things other than column names in `aes(...)` but this can and often does lead to unexpected (even bizarre) results. *Don't do it!*.

The reason, basically, is that `ggplot` does not evaluate the arguments to `aes(...)` immediately, but rather stores them as expressions in a `ggplot object`, and evaluates them when you plot or print that object. This is why, for example, you can add layers to a plot and ggplot is able to dynamically rescale the x- and y-limits, something that does not work with `plot(...)` in base R.

Comment: Thank you so far. Very helpful. But why did my example work if I added points by hand, but not in a for loop? An is there a way to do it without flickering? Maybe some other tool for liveplots?

Comment: Thank you again. very enlightening. I will try to use the animations package. cheers